# restricting multiple user login with the same userid in azure active dirctory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How can i prevent a user logging into azure active directory multiple times with the same account ?  This should be pretty straightforward but i cant find any information anywhere.  Id ideally like to be able to show a page in the browser informing the user that they aren't allowed to login multiple times with the same account

Comment: Ahh so you want to prevent multiple users from sharing an account?

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you could not restrict the user login azure active directory multiple times with the same account. You could limit the login hour for the user, or you could enable [Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-mfa-applications)(MFA) enhance the login security level and reduce login risk. For example, once enabling MFA, you could require the login user to confirm by using a phone call or text code after entering the user password.

Comment: MFA is a pretty good option if OP wants to restrict multiple users from sharing an account. It won't prevent it 100%, but it'll at least make it more tedious to do.